# Which directories appear in Windows Explorer's drop down menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

In a Windows Explorer (Win7) window, the drop down menu from the address bar at the top the shows a list of directories, which is supposed to be the Recent Locations.

[image]

What determines which folders appear there? I would've thought it's recently or frequently used folders, or perhaps directories that I've added to my sidebar's Favorites list, but that's not the case. Most of the entries I haven't been to in a very long time.

Answer (score 3):

These are the typed paths. When you manually type path in the address bar of the folder browser, it will be added to the list.

Comment: Further info - I had to type from the root, to get a new entry to stick in this menu. I tried just adding-by-typing one subfolder name to a very long path I was viewing in WinExplorer, and it only showed up on the menu temporarily, in the folder widow I typed it in; but then it was gone for other explorer windows, new or already open. But, when I typed the whole laborious path from the root up, suddenly that full path showed up, as well as the path to the subfolder that I only entered by the subfolder name without the full path. Still don't know what the rule is, but now I can control the menu

Answer (score 2):

I'm speaking from a Vista background, but there might be two dropdowns you might be referring to. The one next to the `Back - Next` buttons is the history of operations you made in Explorer referring folders (like History in IE or Firefox). There is another dropdown, on the address bar, that contains the parent directories of the folder you're at.

Comment: thanks! I mean the address bar one. rather than the parent directories, I mean the locations in the actual drop down menu that appears when you click on the down arrow.

Comment: Like I said, when you click on the down arrow, Explorer should tell you the treeview list of parent directories. The only other thing I remember is that while you're typing an address, Explorer will try to help you and predict the most likely addresses. While searching, I also found that some addresses might refer to Previous Locations, so, I'll add the [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-explorers-address-bar-dropdown-list-of/272d7dee-3d6c-4fad-9439-2f84068764b1?page=1), if that was what you were referring to (I'm not currently in Vista).

Comment: +1 for useful related info. Not the OP, but appreciated. The dropdown menu you mention at the back arrows is the back-or-forward arrows paths buffer apparently. Thanks